# The second column on my report is not formatting the same as the first column

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting

I need it to look like a table so it looks similar to what the old program's report did. I finally figured out how to do columns, then I added lines between each field both horizontal and vertical. The first column formats with this correctly, but the second column only adds the line horizontally. See the screenshot:

[image: Columns]

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I prefer the new version. Less clutter.  But if you want to add them, you can:

1. Put borders around your cells.  This may cause some problems with overlap, but you can work around that by only putting borders around the Item and Price fields.
2. Use your line tool to draw 4 vertical lines in both the Detail and Report Header sections.

Comment: I've done that and it still doesn't spill over into the second column.

Comment: I ended up putting borders around my cells. Thanks, PowerUser!

Answer (score 0):

Its blind guess.. If you have copied the lines from first column there is possibility that they don't showup in second column.

Try to draw the lines again and check.

Comment: I ended up saving the report, closing out, going back in and adding borders to the cells, lining them up absolutely perfectly and calling it good. I am now getting the results I was looking for!